# Matching "first tone" of Chinese characters

Tags: javascript

This is the input (Chinese):

```
ㄨㄛˇ ㄍㄤ ㄍㄤ ㄗㄞˋ ㄇㄤˊ
```

I would like to match the set of characters that don't have Chinese tones (`ˊ ˇ ˋ`) on the right (which is considered the "first tone").

In other words, I would like to match these (the ones between the `[]`):

```
ㄨㄛˇ [ㄍㄤ] [ㄍㄤ] ㄗㄞˋ ㄇㄤˊ
```

I can't use `\w+` to match the consonants and vowels because they are not letters.

Is there a way to match them?

RegExr: https://regexr.com/72tkj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match the actual bopomofo range, and exclude matches that still have more bopomofo characters or tone marks following:

```
[\u3105-\u312f]+(?![\u3105-\u312fˊˇˋ])
```

Comment: Thanks, so I have to write the unicode of all the bopomofo's to make it work with every bopomofo? For example, with a large body of Chinese text?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The quantity of text should not matter. Big text or small text, you use the same characters. You don't need to list them all, just use the range, `[\u3105-\u312f]` as I did. There are also additional bopomofo (for Cantonese and other languages where basic bopomofo are not enough), if you need those you need to add the extended bopomofo range: `[\u3105-\u312f\u31a0-\u31bf]`.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were matching only two characters. I didn't notice it was a range. Apologies.